# How to put a block in a minecart in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to place a block (a cake) in a minecart with an offset but I cannot find a solution I have tried using

> /summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {CustomDisplayTile:1,DisplayTile:cake,DisplayOffset:1}

but this does not work, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: There is/was a way to do this using a piston in even older versions; I could do it on my PS3.  It was part of a video on building a creeper farm; putting a lava block into a minecart as the killbox.  Now I can't find the video.  I mention this because it *doesn't* require the command line.

Answer (score 2):

In 1.13, a minecart's display block is now determined by a `DisplayState` compound, which looks like this:

[image: DisplayState NBT format]

Which means to summon a minecart with cake in it, you should use the following command:

```
/summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {CustomDisplayTile:1b,DisplayState:{Name:"cake"},DisplayOffset:1}
```

You can also use this to specify block-states. For example:

```
/summon minecart ~ ~ ~ {CustomDisplayTile:1b,DisplayState:{Name:"redstone_lamp",Properties:{lit:"true"}}}
```